# How can I do load balancing in my Rasa chatbot?

Tags: load-balancing, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

Can somebody suggest to me how can I do load balancing in a Rasa Chatbot? There is not much documentation or tutorials available.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your Rasa bot via Rasa X, you can do so in Kubernetes or Openshift. Both of these cluster environments provide native load balancing and the availability to scale pods when you have more traffic. https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/installation-and-setup/openshift-kubernetes/

Comment: I have deployed the rasa bot using docker. Does docker provide load balancing? @ella

Comment: That's sort of what docker swarm is for, but there's no official Rasa support for docker swarm. I'd definitely recommend a cluster env for load balancing. These tools are built on top of docker for that exact use case -- rebuilding it in docker itself is sort of reinventing the wheel.